# IE Drop Down Menu Retreating Beyond First Item

Tags: css, internet-explorer, html

I have a purely CSS driven menu that is having some IE problems. In IE 8 and 9, the drop down retreats if you mouse beyond the first item. In 7 it's hidden behind other elements. (don't care as much about 7 but thought I'd put it out there as well).

**Markup follows this basic structure.**

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li></li>
    <li>
      <ul>
        <li></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

**CSS**

```
/* Main Navigation */
nav#main-nav > .menu {
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 100%;
    padding: .4em 0;
    overflow: visible;
    position: relative;
    background: transparent url(../images/bg-element-gradient.png) repeat-x top left; /* Old browsers */ 
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(219,227,236,1) 10%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 50%, rgba(219,227,236,1) 90%); 
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(10%,rgba(219,227,236,1)), color-stop(50%,rgba(255,255,255,1)), color-stop(90%,rgba(219,227,236,1)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(219,227,236,1) 10%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 50%,rgba(219,227,236,1) 90%); 
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(219,227,236,1) 10%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 50%,rgba(219,227,236,1) 90%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(219,227,236,1) 10%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 50%,rgba(219,227,236,1) 90%); 
}
nav#main-nav > .menu > li {
    padding: 0 1.9%;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
}
nav#main-nav > .menu > li:not(:last-child) {
    border-right: 1px solid #d1d1d1;
}

nav#main-nav > .menu > li.last {
    margin-right: 0;
}

/* dropdown */
nav#main-nav > .menu li.expanded:hover > ul {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 100;
    -webkit-transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.100, 0.250, 1.000); 
    -moz-transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.100, 0.250, 1.000); 
    -ms-transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.100, 0.250, 1.000); 
    -o-transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.100, 0.250, 1.000); 
    transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.100, 0.250, 1.000); /* ease (default) */
}

/* Main-Nav: Level 2 */
nav#main-nav > .menu > li.expanded > ul {
    z-index: 100;
    list-style: none;
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 155px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 1.6em;
    left: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    min-width: 100%;
    border-left: 1px solid #d1d1d1;
    border-right: 1px solid #d1d1d1;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #d1d1d1;
    font-size: .8em;
    line-height: 1em;
    -webkit-transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.100, 0.250, 1.000); 
    -moz-transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.100, 0.250, 1.000); 
    -ms-transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.100, 0.250, 1.000); 
    -o-transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.100, 0.250, 1.000); 
    transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.100, 0.250, 1.000); /* ease (default) */
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0.95) 0%, rgba(219,227,236,0.95) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(255,255,255,0.95)), color-stop(100%,rgba(219,227,236,0.9))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0.95) 0%,rgba(219,227,236,0.95) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0.95) 0%,rgba(219,227,236,0.95) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0.95) 0%,rgba(219,227,236,0.95) 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0.95) 0%,rgba(219,227,236,0.95) 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#e6ffffff', endColorstr='#e6dbe3ec',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
    }
    nav#main-nav > .menu ul li {
    float: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    }
    nav#main-nav > .menu > li.expanded > ul > li {
    display: block;
    padding: 0 0 1em 1.1em;
    z-index: 101;
    }
    nav#main-nav >.menu > li.expanded > ul > li:first-child {
    padding-top: 1em;
    }
    nav#main-nav > .menu > li.expanded > ul > li > a {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    padding: 0 1.1em .25em .25em;
    }
    nav#main-nav > .menu > li:last-child > ul {
    position: absolute;
    left: -75px;
    }
    nav#main-nav > .menu:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
    line-height: 0;
    height: 0;
    }
    html[xmlns] .menu {
    display: block;
    }

    * html .menu {
    height: 1%;
    }
```

To see it live, visit recognia.com.

Answer (score 0):

`:not` and `:last-child` pseudo classes are not supported in IE7/IE8. Maybe that is the reason of the strange behavior. I tested live example using IE8 and the last menu item seems to work, but not the others.

you can check IE selectors compatibility here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc351024(v=vs.85).aspx

Hope this information can help to solve your problem.

**EDIT:**

new idea: your menu is retreating when you pass over the the slider and not when you pass the first item! You have layers problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. But thank you. I'm referring to the links in each individual menu. While running your mouse down the list, it will retreat when you descend further than the first item.

Comment: new idea: layer problem, the menu retrieve when you pass over the slider